# Pass string from php to flash

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I'm just trying out PHP and AS3 in Flash CS6. I want a few strings to be passed from PHP to Actionscript3 and store them in an array. Is this possible?

Currently I'm doing this. My PHP code is

```
<?php
    echo "one,two,three,four";
?>
```

and AS3 code is:

```
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("please7.php");
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();           
myLoader.load(myRequest);
myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(event:Event):void {
    var variables:String = event.target.data;
    trace(variables);
    var arr1:Array = new Array();
    arr1 = variables.split(","); 
    trace(arr1);
    }
```

This gives me this output:

```
<?php
    echo "one,two,three,four";
?>
```

If I use `myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;` instead of `myLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;` ..I'm getting this error

> Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be
>   a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.

I want the output to be a simple [one two three four]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your PHP file actually on a server? (should be web server or even some Local Host server address). Until then its just a text file and doesn't "echo" anything. You're simply reading the words (text) in the PHP instead of requesting a valid server result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like following, it will be passed as a query-string

In PHP

```
<?php
 echo 'q=' . htmlentities($your_data);
?>
```

In AS3

```
var urlLoader:URLurlLoader = new URLurlLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLurlLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
urlLoader.load(new URLRequest("somefile.php")); 

function onComplete (event:Event):void {
    trace (urlLoader.data.q.toString());
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this means?

<?php
 **echo 'q=' + htmlentities($your_data);**
?>

Comment: it will work as key/value item where as htmlEntities will encode special characters into html equivalent entities like `&` into `&amps;`

Comment: Thankyou for your help :)

Comment: This is giving me this. Does this mean that my PHP code isn't interpreted as PHP? Something wrong with server?

%3C%3Fphp%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24your%5Fdata=%22One%2C%20Two%2C%20Three%2C%20Four%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20echo%20%27q%3D%27%20%20%20htmlentities%28%24your%5Fdata%29%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20echo%20%24your%5Fdata%3B%0D%0A%3F%3E

Comment: There was a typo in concatenation string above. try again.